# Python splitting an int based on the char length

Tags: python, split, int

I’m new to python and would like to do a simple function. I’d like to read the input array and if the value is more than 4 digits, to then split it then print the first value then the second value.

I’m having issues splitting the number and getting rid of 0’s inbetween; so for example 1006, would become 1, 6.

Input array:

```
a = [ 1002, 2, 3, 7 ,9, 15, 5992]
```

Desired output in console:

```
1, 2
2
3
7
9
15
59,92
```

Comment: Your desired output is not making much sense. Why is 5992 59, 92? shouldn't it be 52?

Comment: Your desired output seems obscure. Please explain the logic behind it more clearly. You seem to be introducing zeros in a way that doesn't match your problem description. Also -- what have you tried? Without seeing your code we can only guess as to what the "issues" are that you allude to.

Comment: Looks like casting to `str`, slicing, (then casting back to `int` if required) should do the trick. What did you tried so far?

Comment: If `5992` becomes `59, 92` why should `1002` become `1, 2` instead of `10, 2`?

Comment: What should `1020` become? `1, 20` or `1, 2`?

Comment: I’ve removed the 0’s to remove confusion. Essentially I’m aiming to split the value if it’s longer than 4 digits.

Comment: 1020 would become 1, 20 @barmar

Comment: We understand that you want to split it, but the logic of the results isn't clear. Where do you want to split it?

Comment: Why does `1006` become `1, 6` instead of `10, 6` if you want to split every 2 digits?

Comment: Split after the second digit then removal of second 0 if there is one.

Comment: You say "Split after the second digit then removal of second 0 if there is one" but you also say that "1020 would become 1, 20" -- those two statements are not consistent. Your first statement, applied to `1020` would yield `10, 2` rather than `1, 20`.

Comment: Because how else would you differentiate 2 and 20? I’m hoping to get rid of the 0 IF it’s in the 2nd position AFTER splitting the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abstract the splitting into a function and then use a list comprehension to map that function over the list. The following can be tweaked (it matches more of what you had before one of your edits). It can be tweaked of course:

```
def split_num(n):
    s = str(n)
    if len(s) < 4:
        return 0, n
    else:
        a,b = s[:2], s[2:]
        if a[1] == '0': a = a[0]
        return int(a), int(b)

nums = [1002, 2, 3, 7 ,9, 15, 5992]
result = [split_num(n) for n in nums]

for a,b in result:
    print(a,b)
```

Output:

```
1 2
0 2
0 3
0 7
0 9
0 15
59 92
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a list of the non-zero digits in the original list, you can use this:

```
a = [ 1002, 2, 3, 7 ,9, 15, 5992]
strings = [str(el) for el in a]
str_digits = [char for el in strings for char in el if char != '0']
```

and if you want the digits as ints, you can do:

```
int_digits = [int(el) for el in str_digits]
```

or go straight to

```
int_digits = [int(char) for el in strings for char in el if char != '0']
```

I'm not sure what the logic is behind your desired output is, though, so if this isn't helpful I'm sorry.